# Force my scrapy spider to stop crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

is there a chance to stop crawling when specific if condition is true (like scrap_item_id == predefine_value ). My problem is similar to [Scrapy - how to identify already scraped urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871613/scrapy-how-to-identify-already-scraped-urls) but I want to 'force' my scrapy spider to stop crawling after discover the last scraped item.

Comment: Ok got it ... I'm pretty sure there is a better solution but 
from scrapy.project import crawler
crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'closespider_blee')
works

Comment: That solution seems fine. It's used in the scrapy source too (e.g. contrib/closespider.py)

Answer (score 44):

In the latest version of Scrapy, available on GitHub, you can raise a CloseSpider exception to manually close a spider.

In the [0.14 release note doc](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/wiki/Scrapy-0.14-release-notes) is mentioned: "Added CloseSpider exception to manually close spiders (r2691)"

Example as per the docs:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
  if 'Bandwidth exceeded' in response.body:
    raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
```

See also: http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=closeSpider

Comment: It succeeds to force stop, but not fast enough. It still lets some Request running. I hope Scrapy will provide a better solution in the future.

Comment: From my observations, it finishes the requests which were already fired, no?

Answer (score 12):

This question was asked 8 months ago but I was wondering the same thing and have found another (not great) solution.  Hopefully this can help the future readers.

I'm connecting to a database in my Pipeline file, if the database connection is unsuccessful, I wanted the Spider to stop crawling (no point in collecting data if there's nowhere to send it).  What I ended up doing was using:

```
from scrapy.project import crawler
crawler._signal_shutdown(9,0) #Run this if the cnxn fails.
```

This causes the Spider to do the following:

```
[scrapy] INFO: Received SIGKILL, shutting down gracefully. Send again to force unclean shutdown.
```

I just kind of pieced this together after reading your comment and looking through the "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.12.0.2543-py2.7.egg/scrapy/crawler.py" file.  I'm not totally sure what it's doing, the first number delivered to the function is the signame (for example, using 3,0 instead of 9,0 returns error `[scrapy] INFO: Received SIGKILL...`

Seems to work well enough though.  Happy scraping.

EDIT:
I also suppose that you could just force your program to shut down with something like:

```
import sys
sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning extension - right now it is really way to go. Here are docs: http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/0.12/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider

Comment: The thing that I dislike about the Close Spider extension is that it can only be initiated by four conditions (timeout, itempassed, pagecount, errorcount; as far as I know).  What would be nice is if you could make your own conditions to close the spider, so that it's closed when there is a specific occurance (ex. a certain word is scraped).

Comment: the link to the extension is down

Comment: The new link to the extension is: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/closespider.py

Answer (score 3):

From a pipeline, I prefer the following solution.

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    spider.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='duplicate')
```

Source: [Force spider to stop in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749659/force-spider-to-stop-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

Tried lots of options nothing works. This dirty hack do the trick for Linux:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```

This sends SIGINT signal two times to scrapy. Second signal forces shutdown

Comment: I tried this on Linux, but I got: "NameError: name 'signal' is not defined"

Comment: add ```import signal```