# Terminate Scrapy if a condition is met

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a scraper using scrapy in python. It contains 100 start_urls.

I want to terminate the scraping process once a condition is met. 
ie terminate scraping of a particular div is found. By terminate I mean it should stop scraping all the urls .

Is it possible

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448724/force-my-scrapy-spider-to-stop-crawling

Comment: You may have a look at the [`CloseSpider` Exception](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider), but requests that are still in progress (HTTP request sent, response not yet received) will still be parsed. No new request will be processed though.

Comment: @paultrmbrth am getting the following error on using this :           raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
      exceptions.NameError: global name 'CloseSpider' is not defined

Comment: Simply add this line at the beginning of your source file: `from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider`

Comment: @paultrmbrth you should post it as an answer. Deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`CloseSpider` exception](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider).

Add the following line somewhere at the top of your source file:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
```

And when you detect that your termination condition is met, simply do something like

```
        raise CloseSpider('termination condition met')
```

in your callback method (instead of returning or yielding an `Item` or `Request`).

Note that requests that are still in progress (HTTP request sent, response not yet received) will still be parsed. No new request will be processed though.