# How do I stop crawling and close spider based on condition?

Tags: scrapy

I have a spider which fetches the latest url based on a particular date range from a paginated webpage. When it gets all latest urls, my spider has to be closed. 
 How to close a spider? 
I referred question : [Force stop the spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448724/force-my-scrapy-spider-to-stop-crawling) 
But raising an exception to close the spider is not pleasing to me. 
Is there any other way I could achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Close Spider extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider).

The conditions for closing a spider can be configured through the following settings:

`CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT` `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` `CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT`

Comment: Is it possible to add custom flags to this list?

Comment: You can create your own extension or extend the close spider one easily if you want to extend this functionality. [github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/closespider.py)

Comment: Thanks @dataisbeautiful sounds to be better solution than raising exception. I will surely try it.