# How to stop scrapy crawler

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to stop the spider if some condition is met
I tried doing this:
`raise CloseSpider('Some Text')` and

```
sys.exit("SHUT DOWN EVERYTHING!")
```

But it is not stopping.
Here is the Code writing raise exception instead of return also wont work as the spider continues to crawl:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

from tutorial.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
import sys

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"
    allowed_domain = ["jabong.com"]
    start_urls = [
            "http://www.jabong.com/women/shoes/sandals/?page=1"
        ]

    page_index = 1

    def parse(self,response):
        products = response.xpath('//li')

        if products:
            for product in products:
                item = DmozItem()
                item_url = product.xpath('@data-url').extract()
                item_url = "http://www.jabong.com/" + item_url[0] if item_url else ''   
                if item_url:
                        request=Request(url=item_url,callback=self.parse_page2,meta={"item":item},
                                headers={"Accept":
                        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"})
                    request.meta['item'] = item
                    yield request
        else:
            return

        self.page_index += 1
            if self.page_index:
                    yield Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/women/shoes/sandals/?page=%s" %                        (self.page_index),
            headers={"Referer": "http://www.jabong.com/women/shoes/sandals/",
                 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                        callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        sizes=[]
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['site_name'] = 'jabong'
        item['tags'] = ''
        yield item
```

Update:
Instead of return even if i raise closespider my spider is not stopping

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448724/force-my-scrapy-spider-to-stop-crawling Hope it help.

Comment: Raising `CloseSpider` should do the trick, show the code where you use it. I bet the exception is just not raised for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` will also work here, not forcibly but due to the crawling logic - because you are not yielding any more requests.
Keep in mind however, that what you may interpret as "the spider doesn't close" is actually remaining requests in the pipeline that have started to be processed and will take some more time to finish processing. Thus, the spider will not stop the same instant that `return` is executed, because there are still requests in the pipeline. When they are all processed, and if no new ones are created, the spider will eventually stop.