# best practice to stop scrapy crawl when bad request numbers arrived the numbers I seted

Tags: scrapy

I have 400 pages to crawl,for example.And some pages may return 3xx or 4xx .I wish when the numbers of bad 
requests arrived 100,for example. scrapy task auto stop.Thks~

Answer (score 1):

You can use different systems:

- A global variable in the class (which is not recommended but probably is the simplest solution)
- Storing it in the DB using pipelines

Once you have reached the number that you have configured, you can stop the crawler using:

```
if errors > maxNumberErrors:
    raise CloseSpider('message error')
```

or (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073313/446440) answer)

```
from scrapy.project import crawler
crawler._signal_shutdown(9,0)
```

Comment: You can do it in the crawler class for instance. But this is the "easy" and not best solution.